# Android : Mockito (2.0.2-beta) - Cannot mock/spy final classes

Tags: java, android, mockito, android-instrumentation

I am using `mockito-all`, `version: '2.0.2-beta'` in an Android Instrumental test to mock `PowerManager`, which is a final class,

I am getting -

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Cannot mock/spy class android.os.PowerManager
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
- final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types
at com.crsardar.handson.android.mockito.ExampleInstrumentedTest.useAppContext(ExampleInstrumentedTest.java:38)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4.run(AndroidJUnit4.java:101)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:56)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:384)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1932)
```

My app's `build.gradle` is as follows -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.crsardar.handson.android.mockito"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
}
```

My instrumental test case is as follows -

```
package com.crsardar.handson.android.mockito;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * @see <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing">Testing documentation</a>
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    private Context mockedContext = null;

    @Test
    public void useAppContext() {

        PowerManager mockedPowerManager = mock(PowerManager.class);
        System.out.println("Before mockedPowerManager = " + mockedPowerManager.hashCode());

        mockedContext = mock(Context.class);

        when(mockedContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockedPowerManager);

        System.out.println("After mockedPowerManager = " + mockedContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE).hashCode());
    }
}
```

None of the existing post in StackOverflow were helpful, any help is really appreciated

Comment: Can you post PoweManager code?

Comment: it is standard Android SDK class(API Level 25)

`android.os.PowerManager`

Comment: Oh right, sorry I thought that your were using one custom, ok yes when a class is final can't be mockeable you can use
You could use the ShadowPowerManager let me add an answer with detail

Comment: Have you tried using PowerMock?

Answer (score 2):

Can use ShadowPowerManager by following way:

```
  private PowerManager powerManager;
  private ShadowPowerManager shadowPowerManager;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    powerManager =  (PowerManager)ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    shadowPowerManager = shadowOf(powerManager);
    shadowPowerManager.setIsScreenOn(false);
  }
```

Comment: `ShadowPowerManager` will be my custom class?

Comment: No, it won't. You have to add this class from http://robolectric.org/javadoc/3.0/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPowerManager.html

Comment: can not find anything like -
`import static org.mockito.Mockito.shadowOf`

Comment: if you have any GitHub reference, that will be great

Comment: Of course, https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thanks

But `shadowOf ` which function is it?

Comment: You can take a look this example https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/robolectric/src/test/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowPowerManagerTest.java

Comment: @CRSardar if this solved your question please accept as answer.

Comment: @10426557 please see my answer bellow.
Sorry, it was not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After researching more I found - As of this version of Mockito, it is NOT possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried to run with local jvm,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PowerManager.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest2 {

    @Mock
    private Context mContext;

    @Mock
    private PowerManager mPowerManager;


    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        Mockito.when(mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mPowerManager);
        System.out.println("After mockedPowerManager = " + mContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE).hashCode());

    }
}
```

Here's the output,

```
After mockedPowerManager = 793319856
After mockedPowerManager = 1340086275
```

Comment: it is also working on local JVM(i.e. as jUnit test), but not working inside Android Runtime (i.e. as Instrumental Test)

Comment: can you give a try with Robolectric

Comment: Robolectric where Android context are not available like JUnit test, correct?

Comment: Application application = RuntimeEnvironment.application; and application.getAppContext() !!

Comment: if we add this `androidTestCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1'`
we will get `com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`